# Print error if cin includes integer before string

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop, cin

I am writing a program where the user can input any string they want and it will be valid UNLESS they enter an integer before the string.
For example:

```
input: hi
output: hi is valid
input: 1hi
output: 1hi is invalid. It starts with a number
```

This is what i have so far but it keep printing out "hi is valid" if i input "hi" and "1hi is valid" if i input 1hi.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string input;
int main()
{
    while (input != "quit")
    {
        cin >> input;

        if (input == "1" + input)
            cout << input << "in not valid. Reason: Started with a number.";

        cout << input << " is valid.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**answer has been resolved.
using isdigit as a solution to the problem.**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with *`if(input == "1" + input)`*? I think you need something like `char c = input[0]; if(isdigit(c)) break;`.

Comment: They will never be equal. Effectively, the left hand side is a string like *`"X"`*. The right hand side creates a temporary and is effectively  *`"1X"`*. Like I said, they will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? :

```
if (input[0] >= 48 && input[0] <= 57) {
    std::cout << input << " is not valid";
}
```

By seeing the ASCII table, I think this will work.

EDIT - `(input == "1" + input)` will never be true.

Comment: Why not use [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)? Or why not use *`if (input[0] >= '0' && input[0] <= '9')`*? What's the point of using ASCII tables?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't think about it, this is my fault. std::isdigit seems better, I agree. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use isdigit:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string input;
int main()
{
    while (input != "quit")
    {
        cin >> input;

        if (isdigit(input.at(0)))
            cout << input << "in not valid. Reason: Started with a number.";
        else
            cout << input << " is valid.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```